# Textinput is floating in JQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I am using jquerymobile for the UI desgin. My problem is that the textinput in the Jquery Mobile floats around.
Let me show you what I mean

Here is my screen

[image]

***Now the Selection 4 is and EditText(Android) / Textinput(Jquery), and I am typing `Hello` onto it***

[image]

***Now If I try to scroll the screen I can see the Input text being floated on the screen***

[image]   [image]

***But if the TextInput losses the focus then its fine***

[image]

***But when you select the TextInput again then the problem occurs again***

[image]

***Can any one tell me the solution for this issue***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to add this piece of code thus disabling the transtions in the 'mobileinit' event

```
$.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none';
$.mobile.defaultDialogTransition = 'none';
$.mobile.transitionFallbacks.slideout = 'none';
```

Like this

```
<script src="js/cordova.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
       if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Android") != -1)
       {
         $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none';
         $.mobile.defaultDialogTransition = 'none';
         $.mobile.transitionFallbacks.slideout = 'none';
       }
    });
</script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>  
<link href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

**Note : This code must be run after you include jQuery Core and before you include jQuery Mobile.**